# Primefaces Autocomplete with barcode reader

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I want to search an items with the name, code or barcode in a JSF/JPA/Primefaces application. I have used It works fine when using name or code. When we manually type the barcode it works fine as well. But when I used the barcode reader as it enters a carriage return, item is not selecte. How can I use a barcode reader in primefaces autocomplete?

```
<p:autoComplete accesskey="i"   forceSelection="true"  id="acStock" 
                                                        value="#{pharmacySaleController.stock}" 
                                                        converter="stockCon" 
                                                        completeMethod="#{pharmacySaleController.completeAvailableStocks}" 
                                                        var="i" itemLabel="#{i.itemBatch.item.name}" itemValue="#{i}" 
                                                        style="width: 50px!important;">
                                            <p:column headerText="Item">
                                                <h:outputLabel value="#{i.itemBatch.item.name}" ></h:outputLabel>
                                            </p:column>
                                            <p:column headerText="Code">
                                                <h:outputLabel value="#{i.itemBatch.item.code}" ></h:outputLabel>
                                            </p:column>
                                            <p:column headerText="Rate">
                                                <h:outputLabel value="#{i.itemBatch.retailsaleRate}" >
                                                    <f:convertNumber pattern="#,##0.00" ></f:convertNumber>
                                                </h:outputLabel>
                                            </p:column>
                                            <p:column headerText="Stocks">
                                                <h:outputLabel value="#{i.stock}" >
                                                    <f:convertNumber pattern="#,###" ></f:convertNumber>
                                                </h:outputLabel>
                                            </p:column>
                                            <p:column headerText="Expiary">
                                                <h:outputLabel value="#{i.itemBatch.dateOfExpire}" >
                                                    <f:convertDateTime pattern="dd MMMM yyyy" ></f:convertDateTime>
                                                </h:outputLabel>
                                            </p:column>
                                            <p:ajax event="focus" process="acStock :#{p:component('cmbPs')}"  ></p:ajax>
                                            <p:ajax event="itemSelect"   listener="#{pharmacySaleController.handleSelect}"  update="txtQty txtRate focusQty" ></p:ajax>
                                        </p:autoComplete>
```

Comment: From what I understand, the String is correctly "inputted" from the barcode scanner correct?

Comment: Yes. Reader inputs the numbers correctly and adds a carriage return at the end. It works fine if we type the numbers manually.

Comment: You need to implement a change event handler with: `<p:ajax event="change" listener="#{pharmacySaleController.handleChange}"  update="txtQty txtRate focusQty"/>` and in the method you need to select an item via the value obtained in the component.

Answer (score 0):

It was published by Primefaces Developers that they will add a  from version 5.1, so that there will be no need to generate barcodes ourselves.